# Create multiple model in laravel to belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 models, `Service` and `Schedule`.

`Schedule` model has this relationship:

```php
public function service() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service','services_has_schedules','services_service_id','schedules_schedule_id);
}
```

`Service` model have this relationship:

```php
public function schedule() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Schedule','services_has_schedules','services_service_id','schedules_schedule_id');
}
```

In frontend, this send me arrays `day[]` (day name), `init[]` (open hour), `finit[]` (close hour)

[image: example of what I have]

In the controller I want to know how to create multiple `Schedule` to `sync()` with `Service`

[image]

Comment: if you use sync, you are going to add, in the pivot table, all IDs that you sent on `$schedules`, but if you already have data there relating `Service` with `Schedule`, all missing IDs in `$schedules` will be deleted from the relation, like the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) says.

Comment: according to the test I must use a foreach to go through the days and inside the doing the functions to create  **Schedule** and dont  use `sync()` but use `attach()`, im gonna test and share whats happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `syncWithoutDetaching` to keep the existing records and add the new ones.

> If you do not want to detach existing IDs, you may use the
>   syncWithoutDetaching method:
>
> `$user->roles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1, 2, 3]);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships